# python pytest - How can I get a test markers inside its fixture methods?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have test in pytest and added some markers such as: '`@pytest.mark.xfail`', the test have several fixture methods.
How can I get all the markers of certain test using a fixture method?

Comment: Do you want to get the markers inside the fixture? That can be done using the fixture request. What is your use case?

Comment: yes, I'm indeed using the request for similar tasks, but I didn't find there any info about the markers

Answer (score 5):

The markers can be taken from the fixture request `node` attribute using `iter_markers`, as can be seen in this (nonsensical) example:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def get_marks(request):
    marks = [m.name for m in request.node.iter_markers()]
    if request.node.parent:
        marks += [m.name for m in request.node.parent.iter_markers()]
    yield marks


@pytest.mark.parametrize('number', [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.foo
@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_marks(get_marks, number):
    print(get_marks)
    assert 'xfail' in get_marks
    assert number == 42
```

This gives the output:

```
...
xfail                                      [100%]['parametrize', 'xfail', 'foo']

get_marks = ['parametrize', 'xfail', 'foo'], number = 3

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('number', [1, 2, 3])
    @pytest.mark.foo
    @pytest.mark.xfail
    def test_marks(get_marks, number):
        print(get_marks)
        assert 'xfail' in get_marks
>       assert number == 42
E       assert 3 == 42
```

*Update*:
Use the correct public call to get the markers as proposed by @hoefling.

Comment: There's also `request.node.iter_markers()` that will yield only the markers. I'd pay attention to the fixture scope though, `request.node` is the session in session-scoped, test class in class-scoped, module in module-scoped fixtures etc. The most general solution would probably combine `request.node.iter_markers()` with `request.node.parent.iter_markers()` while available.

Comment: @hoefling - thanks, that sounds more reasonable, but it it doesn't work for me. There is an `iter_markers` in the item that is passed in hooks (that is actually used in the other answer), but none in `request.node`, as far as I can see.

Comment: Use `request.node.iter_markers()`, not `request.iter_markers()`. In function-scoped fixtures, `request.node` is the same `item` that is passed in hooks.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it doesn't work? If I replace `[m for m in request.keywords if ...]` with `[m.name for m in request.node.iter_markers()]` in your fixture example, I get the same output as yours.

Comment: Ok, my bad - I used a venv with an older pytest version. After upgrading pytest it works. Thanks a lot - I will update the answer!

Comment: Yeah, `get_markers` was reworked into `iter_markers` somewhere around version 4 :-)

Answer (score 1):

One method is already described by @MrBean, here's one another approach using `pytest_runtest_setup` in `conftest.py`. By combiantion of global variable and `pytest_runtest_setup` which is pytest's own method, you can get current test marker.

This approach would give you markers of both class level and function level.

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

marker_name = [] #Global variable so you can use it everywhere

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    global marker_name
    marker_name.clear() #If you would not clear this, it would append every test's marker, test by test. 
    for mark in item.iter_markers():
        marker_name.append(mark.name)


@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True) #Note here, autouse=true.
def my_fixture(request):
    request.instance.test_marker=marker_name #assign it to request's session so you can use it in other fixture and in tests as well

@pytest.fixture
def some_other_fixture(request):
    test_marker=request.instance.test_marker #access marker in fixture
```

**test_file.py** (Access that marker variable inside test using request.instance.test_marker.)

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.class_marker
class TestClass:
    @pytest.mark.my_test
    @pytest.mark.xfail
    def test_foo(self,request):
        print(request.instance.test_marker) #output :  ['xfail', 'my_test', 'class_marker']

    @pytest.mark.my_test_two
    @pytest.mark.xfail
    def test_foo_two(self,request):
        print(request.instance.test_marker) #output :  ['xfail', 'my_test_two', 'class_marker']
```

Hope it would help !!